# ООП в JavaScript

Tags: ооп, javascript

Объясните, как запустить вот такую конструкцию "test.b().c('q')" или подробно почитать об этом? То есть сработали все методы одного объекта, написанные через точку.

```
var test={
'a':0,
'b':function(){test.a=5;return test.a},
'c':function(q){test.a=q+test.a;return test.a;}
};
console.log(test.b().c('q'));
```

Comment: куда запустить?.. на орбиту?.. результат в консоли же

Comment: Можно и на орбиту, но это на будущее. А пока хочу понять как в рамках одного объекта вызывать несколько методов, написанных через точку? Как, например, это реализовано в JQuery.

Comment: Поищите книгу паттерны javascript, Стефанов. Там описывается цепочка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Запустить" эту конструкцию можно вот как:

1. В браузере Google Chrome нажать F12, в появившемся окошке выбрать вкладку "Console", скопировать туда "конструкцию", нажать Enter
2. В FireFox нажать Ctrl+Shift+K, выбрать "Консоль" (по умолчанию выбрана), сделать то же самое, что в предыдущем пункте. Также, если установлено дополнение FireBug, то действия аналогичны пункту 1
3. Для Opera нажать Ctrl+Shift+I, далее как в пункте 1
4. Для всеми любимого синего браузера - нажать F12, найти там консоль, сделать описанное в предыдущих пунктах

Однако код ваш не сработает, поскольку  строка

```
console.log(test.b().c('q'));
```

скорее всего ошибочна - у test.b нет свойства "с".

UPD:

Если вы хотите "как в jQuery" - цепочки вызовов функций, то в таком случае ваши функции должны возвращать сам объект, функции которого вызываются. Что-то наподобие такого:

```
var obj = {
   field: 10,
   a: function(i) {
          this.field += i;
          return this;
      },
 b: function(i) {
          this.field *= i;
          return this;
      }
}
```

Насколько это целесообразно - не знаю. По сути в таком случае функция должна выполнять сразу два действия - что-то там делать, а затем возвращать сам объект для совершенно сторонних целей. Вряд ли это правильно

Comment: вот в этом и вопрос.

Comment: в чем именно?

Comment: Хочу понять как сделать, что бы сработали все методы одного объекта (test), написанные через точку.

Comment: Хм..вообще-то вы хотите получить то, чего в языке просто нет. Ваша функция test.b() возвращает  значение свойства a. Это некое число (0 в данном случае). Почему вы считаете, что у этого числа есть функция с()? Функция c() есть у объекта test, но возвращаете-то вы не его, а только значение одного из его свойств

Comment: @DreamChild я и хочу понять как это сделать. Как, например, это реализовано в JQuery. Мне хотя бы накидать ключевых слов по каким искать. Я даже не знаю как это может называться(

Comment: @andrew68 блин, ну вы поймите одну элементарную вещь - функция возвращает то, что описано ключевым словом return. Если вы возвращаете число, то и работать вы должны с результатом именно как с числом. Если возвращаете объект, то можете работать как с объектом. Судя по всему, те функции в jQuery, о которых вы говорите, возвращают сам объект, благодаря чему при их вызове вы можете писать цепочки методов.

Comment: @DreamChild дошло! спасибо.